# Exclude rule not working in apple-app-site-association file for URLs containing `#` sign

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I'm facing an issue with deep links in iOS. I have a URL that needs to be excluded, and it includes a `#` sign, for example, `https://www.someurl.com/#/register`.

I've tried excluding this path in the apple-app-site-association file using the following declarations:

```
{
  "/": "/#/register/*",
  "exclude": true
},
  "/": "/#/register/",
  "exclude": true
}，
{
  "/": "/#/register",
  "exclude": true
}
```

Despite declaring the exclude rule in the association file, the deep link still opens the app from the web browser. If you've encountered a similar issue and found a solution, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share your experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a url, everything following the # character is part of the *fragment*, not part of the *path*.

This means that you have to use the fragment matching rule, described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks/details/components) in your file.

You want something like

```json
{
   "#": "/register",
   "exclude": true
}
```